# Не отображаются балуны на Яндекс API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Нужно отображать много меток на карте, и что-бы по нажатию открывались балуны.
С помощью документации получилось сделать одну метку и один балун. Но предполагается что их будет много, и я нашла в интернете старый код, в котором метки помещаются в коллекцию, и создается шаблон для отображения балуна.
По итогу :метки на карте отображаются, а вот балуны при нажатию нет. Скорее всего неправильный синтаксис, так как информация 2012 года)). А с документацией я не смогла разобраться.

```
ymaps.ready(init);  
function init(){
    // Создание карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        // Координаты центра карты.
        // Порядок по умолчанию: «широта, долгота».
        // Чтобы не определять координаты центра карты вручную,
        // воспользуйтесь инструментом Определение координат.
        center: [50.91141883648759,34.7973088543701],
        // Уровень масштабирования. Допустимые значения:
        // от 0 (весь мир) до 19.
        zoom: 14,
        controls: [],
        behaviors: []
    });
    //создаю метку
    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark (
      // Координаты метки
      [50.91141883648759,34.7973088543701], {
        name: 'Оперный театр',
                address: 'ул. Белинского, 59',
      });
      //создаю метку
      var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark (
        // Координаты метки
        [50.9011891191192,34.79421894958494], {
          name: 'Театр драмы',
                  address: 'ул. Большая Покровская, д. 13',
        });
     // Создаем коллекцию, в которую будем добавлять метки
        var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
     myCollection
            .add(myPlacemark)
            .add(myPlacemark1);
            
      // Создаем шаблон для отображения контента балуна
      var myBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<h3>$[properties.name]</h3>' +
        '<p><strong>Адрес:</strong> $[properties.address]</p>'
      );
//  Помещаем созданный шаблон в хранилище шаблонов.
// Теперь наш шаблон доступен по ключу 'my#theaterlayout'
        ymaps.layout.storage.add('my#theaterlayout', myBalloonLayout);

        // Задаем наш шаблон для балунов геобъектов коллекции
        myCollection.options.set({
          balloonContentBodyLayout:'my#theaterlayout',
         // Максимальная ширина балуна в пикселах
          balloonMaxWidth: 300
        });

      // Добавление метки на карту
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
}
```

Comment: а в чем разница был между баллуном для одной метки и для нескольких?

Answer (score 1):

Несколько меток в API Яндекс.Карт создается буквально тем же способом, что и одна :') Даже если вам лень читать документацию, загляните в песочницу, там есть множество примеров [на любой вкус](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager).

Что касается вашего кода — вы угадали, он написан под API 2.0 (актуальная версия — 2.1), и нужно поправить синтаксис: вместо `balloonContentBodyLayout` в параметрах коллекции прописать `balloonContentLayout`

```js
ymaps.ready(init);  
function init(){
    // Создание карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        // Координаты центра карты.
        // Порядок по умолчанию: «широта, долгота».
        // Чтобы не определять координаты центра карты вручную,
        // воспользуйтесь инструментом Определение координат.
        center: [50.91141883648759,34.7973088543701],
        // Уровень масштабирования. Допустимые значения:
        // от 0 (весь мир) до 19.
        zoom: 14,
        controls: [],
        behaviors: []
    });
    //создаю метку
    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark (
      // Координаты метки
      [50.91141883648759,34.7973088543701], {
        name: 'Оперный театр',
                address: 'ул. Белинского, 59',
      });
      //создаю метку
      var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark (
        // Координаты метки
        [50.9011891191192,34.79421894958494], {
          name: 'Театр драмы',
                  address: 'ул. Большая Покровская, д. 13',
        });
     // Создаем коллекцию, в которую будем добавлять метки
        var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
     myCollection
            .add(myPlacemark)
            .add(myPlacemark1);
            
      // Создаем шаблон для отображения контента балуна
      var myBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<h3>$[properties.name]</h3>' +
        '<p><strong>Адрес:</strong> $[properties.address]</p>'
      );
//  Помещаем созданный шаблон в хранилище шаблонов.
// Теперь наш шаблон доступен по ключу 'my#theaterlayout'
        ymaps.layout.storage.add('my#theaterlayout', myBalloonLayout);

        // Задаем наш шаблон для балунов геобъектов коллекции
        myCollection.options.set({
          balloonContentLayout:'my#theaterlayout',
         // Максимальная ширина балуна в пикселах
          balloonMaxWidth: 300
        });

      // Добавление метки на карту
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;
             apikey=a2d2f39e-5c7c-4ba9-ba21-f687c5c54471">
</script>
<style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
</style>
```